# When to use transfer and transferral?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, transatlantic-differences

Context: in university, some students transfer from one study programme to another. A manual has been written for them. Is it more natural to call it a "transfer manual" or a "transferral manual"? What is the difference between these terms anyway? Is "transferral" the UK spelling?

Comment: Transferral is defined in the [**Oxford Dictionaries**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/transferral) as "The action of transferring someone or something." There is no U.S. or U.K. variant. "Transfer manual" is probably the more natural on either side of the pond, unless the writer is somehow compelled to add a syllable. On spelling, lexicographers are apparently undecided on this one, but neither spelling seems to be associated with a specific country.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either one.

The normal usage in the US is:

The students are called "transfer students".

> Jim is a transfer student; he was studying engineering last year but he switched to the geology department this semester.

The process, in the abstract, is called "transferral"

> The university has implemented a new transferral process: you no longer need the permission of the Dean of Engineering if you are transferring from chemical engineering to chemistry.

The manual could be called any number of things: "transfer manual", "transferral manual", "guide to academic transfers", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Transferral  ( mass noun) 
Pronunciation: /ˌtransˈfəːr(ə)l/

"The action of transferring someone or something":
‘the transferral of ownership in the form of a takeover'.

There is no U.S. or U.K variant.

Comment: It should have occured to me that this has happened more than once. Whether either spelling is a variant depends upon which dictionary we revere. The [OED's free outlet](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=transferal) returns nothing at all for _transferal_ and the American Heritage dictionary returns nothing at all for _transferral._ Dictionary.com gives pride of place to the single "r," while the Collins dictionary cleverly returns the entry for _transfe**rr**al_ on searches for _transfe**r**al,_ without comment.

Comment: What OED source refers to _transferral_ as the "UK spelling?" Please add a link to your answer. The only OED source I can find doesn't mention the U.K., and returns no result at all for _transfe**r**al_ under "U.S. English."

Comment: I stand corrected. I have re-checked the online link, that I consulted, is not so authentic. Therefore, I am editing my previous post about " transferral".

Comment: According to http://www.dictionary.com/browse/transfer?s=t "transfer" can also be used as a noun meaning "an act of transferring". Therefore this answer does not really answer my question. Is it simply the case that "transferral" emphasises the noun aspect?